# В каком формате телеграмм отправляет голосовые сообщения?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Хочу к боту прикрутить распознавание речи. Использую библиотеку speech_recognition. Ей нужно передать объект класса AudioData, а ему в конструктор надо передать frame_data, sample_rate, sample_width. Какие параметры у голосового сообщения в телеграмм?

Comment: [Voice message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#voice)

Comment: [Audio message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#audio)